# Subscribing to a simple request is the right approach on Angular 2 in this case?

Tags: javascript, angular, laravel, rxjs

I have a Parking System that I use Angular 6 + Laravel for the backend, I have a post that I post some of my problems that were resolved by the DigitalDrifter thank you.

Here is the link: [How to Make a Scheduler Task for Every New Record After 20 Minutes in Laravel?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54175020/how-to-make-a-scheduler-task-for-every-new-record-after-20-minutes-in-laravel/54176606?noredirect=1#comment95258553_54176606)

My system is not 100% good because I having a strange behaviour. Every client must go to the Payment Area and validated your entry. When the client show the ticket to the cashier he validated the entry after the payment clicking in a button called "VALIDATE TICKET"

And my code does this in Angular:

```
validateEntry(ean13: string, value: number) {

    this.spinner.show();
    this.entryService.validateEntry(this.config.role.validateEntryUrl, ean13, value, this.userModel.mov_user_id)
      .pipe(
        catchError(
          (error: any): Observable<any> => {
            this.spinner.hide();
            $('#m_modal_1').modal('hide');
            return this.utilService.errorHandler(error);
          }))
      .subscribe(response => {

      if (response.success != 0) {

        $('#m_modal_1').modal('hide');
        this.spinner.hide();
        swal({
          title: 'Validado!',
          text: response.message,
          type: 'success',
          showCloseButton: true,
          showCancelButton: false,
          showConfirmButton: false
        }).then((result) => {
          $("#mov_ean13_input").focus();
          });


      }else {

        $('#m_modal_1').modal('hide');
        this.spinner.hide();
        swal({
          title: 'Erro!',
          text: response.message,
          type: 'error',
          showCloseButton: true,
          showCancelButton: false,
          showConfirmButton: false
        }).then((result) => {
          $("#mov_ean13_input").focus();
        });

        }


    });


  }
```

And here is the service on Angular 6 :

```
public validateEntry(url: string, ean13: string, value: number, userid: number): Observable<any> {

    console.log(userid);

    return this.http.post(this.mainConfig.config.default.mainUrl + url, { ean13: ean13, value: value, userid: userid });

  }
```

And here is the backend on laravel, this is the code :

```
  public function validateEntry(Request $request){

                 try{

                       $entryean13  = $request->input('ean13');
                       $value       = $request->input('value');
                       $userid      = $request->input('userid');              

                       $this->mdEntry->validatedEntryByEan($entryean13,$value,$userid); 

                       if(empty($this->mdEntry->checkValidEntry($entryean13))){

                         $response["success"] = 0;
                         $response["message"] = "Ocorreu algum erro no servidor, tente validar novamente";  

                       }else {                           

                         $response["success"] = 1;
                         $response["message"] = "Entrada validada com sucesso";                                       

                       }  

                       return $response;    
                } 
                catch(\Exception $e){

                      $response["success"]         = 0;
                      $response["message"]         = "Aconteceu algum erro no processamento, tente novamente em alguns minutos.";
                      $response["erro"]            = $e->getMessage();  
                      return $response;
                }           
          }

And to finish the code area here is the Eloquent that update my table:

  public function validatedEntryByEan($ean13,$valor,$userid){

               Entry::where('mov_entry_ean13', $ean13 )
               ->update(['validated' => 'S',
                         'value' => $valor,
                         'mov_user_id' => $userid]); 

    }
```

When going to Laravel I get the entry EAN_13 code, $value and $userid ( Cashier user ) and do an update on the table and validate the entry,
  the client has 30 minutes to go out.

The problem is 85% are validated but 15% are not and the Cashier always say that they always click the button to validate. Some clients pay and when
  he will go out to the EXIT TOTEM don't let them go, when I pick the ticket and test it he is not validated.

What I'm missing? Is not a human error, everyone clicks the button. I don't know what is wrong, because when the user clicks I return a box that says "ENTRY IS VALIDATED" when ( response.success != 0 ) on Angular.

I do this check to see if the user will be validated for some tests. Now my question this is the right approach for Subscribe? Do you guys think everytime he clicks the button he goes and does a request? or don't? Sorry it is a very noob question, but I want to this work 100%, I put some try and catch and don't receive any error.

Do you think guys that are a Browser issue? Because I run on a Raspberry Pi 3 on Ubuntu Mate an Angular 6 application on a Chromium, I'm thinking of changing the browser for a test.

Comment: may we see `this.entryService.validateEntry` please?

Comment: Hi Randy, I edit my question take a look. I put the Eloquent too

Comment: Thanks - Can you reproduce the error consistently? If not, I would look toward the EAN code input (using a USB Scanner I assume). It is possible 25% of the codes are not valid. If you can produce the error condition consistently, then we need to look at the stream. I would start by adding the error handler to your subscribe method to see if the error is within the Observable stream.

Comment: I dunno why my Laravel will return an "OK" response if is not updated? And when he received the Angular show the "OK" message.

I have a error handler on my subscribe see the pipe there?

Comment: Me either, but it is possible that your server is returning an HTTP status code of 200 (everything is OK now according to Angular), but the data is not what you expect. The only error checking you are doing is against the HTTP status code. Adding the error handler the subscribe method may prove insightful.

Comment: Look this line on Laravel :  if(empty($this->mdEntry->checkValidEntry($entryean13))){

                     $response["success"] = 0;
                     $response["message"] = "Ocorreu algum erro no servidor, tente validar novamente";  

                   }else {                           

                     $response["success"] = 1;
                     $response["message"] = "Entrada validada com sucesso";                                       

                   }

I do a recheck ( that is wrong ), I only do it for testing, I return a JSON response 1

Comment: I see that and understand your point. My suggestion is looking on the client side of things first. So the HTTP request works and we know that, but we don't know if the Observable is behaving properly. You can ignore my suggestion. Sorry I've offered no help. I'm out.

Comment: You are extremely helpful telling the error must be in the client give me some vision. I will make some tests and see what is happening